# Loading data in pig , Error in date conversion

Tags: datetime, hadoop, apache-pig

i have data named campaigndata.csv. it have 272 columns. 272 th column is the date. while loading data in Pig i am getting time conversion error.

Input data at 272 column :

```
Wed, 09/29/10 03:52 PM
```

pig script:

```
     -To load data in Pig
    REGISTER /home/hduser/pigghduserybank.jar;
    DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();

    data0 = load 'campaigndata/CampaignData.csv' using CSVLoader;
    data1 = filter data0 by $0 != 'CLICK_FLG';
    data2 = foreach data1 generate ($0 == 'N' ? 0:1), ($1 == 'N' ? 0:1), $2..$271, ToDate($272,'EEE, MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a');
dump data2;
```

i got error like

[image]

i want the date format as "day" "mm/dd/yyyy" "hh:mm" "am/pm". Then only i can use for further pig scripts.

Comment: Please read the error... Your data doesn't always have the hour and minutes, so your format won't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid exception in ToDate in Pig for individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147906/avoid-exception-in-todate-in-pig-for-individual-rows)

Comment: thank you , for your input. but i want the datetime field as day , mm/dd/yyyy , "hh:mm" "am/pm" separated . please help me on that.and explain me the error in my pig script

Comment: In your error `"Wed, 09/29/10 "` 1) does **not match** `yyyy` and 2) does **not match** `hh:mm a`... You only have shown one "input data", not your entire CSV file, so we cannot say why your code fails other than what the error says

Comment: Besides that, CSVLoader cannot process `Wed, 09/29/10` anyway because it has a comma within the column

Comment: can you please suggest me a pig script for extracting hour from this type of input data

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough of your CSV that generates the error. Then I can help. You don't need to have a 272 column file to reproduce that error. See [mcve] for more information... Otherwise, I already marked this as a duplicate, and as mentioned there, you must filter out the data that does not match your expected date format

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are using ToDate on 273rd column.If your input file has 272 columns then in Pig you can access them using positional notation from $0 to $271.Also note that year is in 'yy' format instead of 'yyyy'

```
data2 = foreach data1 generate ($0 == 'N' ? 0:1), ($1 == 'N' ? 0:1), $2..$270, ToDate($271,'EEE, MM/dd/yy hh:mm a');
```

Comment: See the error, in addition to incorrect column number and 'yy', your data doesn't seem to have the hour and minute values for some of the rows.The error says 'Wed, 09/29/10 ' is too short.This value does not have hour and minute so the ToDate with the date format you have specified will result in an error.

Comment: can u suggest me a method to extract hour from this Input data